# Simple pytest for circumference function?

Tags: python, pytest

I have never used PyTest before and am getting quite confused by it. I simply want to write a basic test for my circumference function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import math

def getCircumference():
    radius = int(input("Please enter a radius size: "))
    circumference = 2 * math.pi * radius
    print("The circumference of the circle is", circumference)
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a unit test is to test valid functioning of functions. That is best accomplished by checking whether a function returns correct result for a known input. Your function takes no input and returns no result, so it is way more complex to test than it should be. It is also less useful in other situations.

What I would expect from a `getCircumference` function would be that it:

- is named get_circumference (because of PEP 8)
- takes one argument: radius
- returns circumference (its name implies that it returns a circumference, after all)

Therefore:

```
def get_circumference(radius):
    return 2 * math.pi * radius
```

Then, the test would do something like:

```
def test_get_circumference():
    # using pytest.approx to avoid problems related to floating point precision
    assert get_circumference(7) == pytest.approx(43.982297150257104)
    assert get_circumference(3.678) == pytest.approx(23.109555559806516)
```

---

On the other hand, if you really want to test the function as it is, you should create a much more complex test which would override `sys.stdin` (in order to fake user input) and `sys.stdout` (in order to verify the output).

Comment: Thank you so much mate, makes a lot of sense now